# CIFS isn't using the specified username when mounting

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, hyper-v, ubuntu-18.04, cifs

I am attempting to run a development server using Hyper-V. The goal is to do my front-end and back-end development in Windows while keeping my back-end files on the virtual server. The server is installed and running, it has an internet connection, and I can SSH into the virtual server but I can't get the shared folders to work.

I have turned on file sharing and shared the specified folder in Windows. I installed CIFS on the virtual server. I set up a static IP address for the virtual server.

I am using the following command

`sudo mount.cifs //DESKTOP-PBAGEL3/Users/Leslie/Documents/Development ~/Documents/Development user=Leslie`

However when cifs attempts to mount it asks for the password for:

`root@//DESKTOP-PBAGEL3/Users/Leslie/Documents/Development`

This of course will not work, I attempted to add `uid=Leslie` and `forceuid` but I still get the same result. I am expecting the password prompt to read:

`Leslie@//DESKTOP-PBAGEL3/Users/Leslie/Documents/Development`

Answer (score 3):

[`man 8 mount.cifs`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs) states:

> ```
> mount.cifs {service} {mount-point} [-o options]
> ```
>
> […]
>
> Options to `mount.cifs` are specified as a comma-separated list of `key=value` pairs.

So instead of sole `user=Leslie` you need `-o user=Leslie`.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem.